# Eclipse - use hyperlink ability without step-into-section

Tags: eclipse

There are two very useful features in eclipse that I would like to be able to use separately. Holding `CTRL-ALT` while clicking a method name will hyperlink you to the method definition, which is super convenient and a feature I use heavily. The issue is that if I do so while paused on a debug, it will not only hyperlink to the function, but will also **execute code** as if I right clicked and hit `Step Into Section`.

My humble question is, is there a way I can hyperlink during a debug without actually executing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move the cursor onto the method (click without CTRL-ALT) and press F3 to open the definition. That doesn't do the step into.

This is also short for "Open Declaration" in the context menu when you right-click the method.